# To use SQL join or not

Tags: sql

I have a query with 2 tables `Table A` and `Table B`.

- `Table_A` : A_ID, B_ID, A3, A4, A5
- `Table_B` : B_ID, B2.

I want value of column `A3` from `Table_A` and `B2` from `Table_B`.

I tried this query:

```
select 
    b.B2, a.A3 
from 
    Table_A a 
join 
    Table_B b on (a.A_ID = b.B_ID)
```

The query returns nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You query seems correct.

Comment: Post enough sample data to illustrate your problem.

Comment: what dbms ? sql server ? please tag .. and what version ?

Comment: you may have null value in B_ID column, or it may simply because there is no matched pair in these two tables

Comment: You know what I was using incorrect sample data.. ugh.. Sorry.. Can I close this??

Comment: You can delete the question.

Comment: also for your join you were using a.B_ID instead of a.A_ID. not sure it was pasting mistake or really query mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that the `B_ID` column in `Table A` is the foreign key to `Table B` - in that case, you need to join on that column:

```
select 
    b.B2, a.A3 
from 
    Table_A a 
inner join 
    Table_B b on a.B_ID = b.B_ID
```

Use `a.B_ID` (not `a.A_ID`) to establish the join between the two tables.